# Building A Query String For Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to programming. I am trying to build up a query string to redirect to another action.

Here is the Action I am trying to redirect to

```
public ActionResult Rate(int Wid, int Uid)
{ 
}
```

Here is the action I am trying to redirect from

```
public ActionResult ConfirmHire2(bool userConfirmed, int confirId)
{
    int Wid = cm.GetCleanerIdFromSale(confirId);
    int Uid = um.GetUserIdFromSale(confirId);
    //I need something to this affect but it is not working
    //return RedirectToAction("'Rate?Wid=' + Wid + 'Uid=' + Uid");
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string parameters aren't part of the action *name*, but rather are values to be added to the URL.  `RedirectToAction` has [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.Object%29) which accepts an object of such parameters, which the framework will use to build the URL:

```
return RedirectToAction("Rate", new { Wid = Wid, Uid = Uid });
```

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Rate", new { Wid = Wid, Uid = Uid });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id as part of the routeValues parameter:

```
return RedirectToAction("Rate", new { Wid = 123, Uid = 123 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult ConfirmHire2 (bool userConfirmed, int confirId)
{
    int Wid = cm.GetCleanerIdFromSale(confirId);
    int Uid = um.GetUserIdFromSale(confirId);
    // Use C#6 `nameof` API for compile time validation of your `RedirectToAction` call
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Rate), new { Wid = Wid, Uid = Uid });
}

public ActionResult Rate(int Wid, int Uid)
{ 
}
```